# How to conduct stress tests on the rcp program?

Tags: rcp, stress-testing, gui-testing

Like the title says, I have a RCP program(Client) need to stress tests. First, 500 people login at the same time. But I do not know what tools or methods to complete it.

Comment: what's your environment ? language ? rpc product-based ?

Comment: environment:win7Java Eclipse RCP Product

Answer (score 0):

As far as I know, you can't have a product installation for multiple user, so that means you'd have to launch 1 instance of X different product installation. 
I don't know any external tool to fit your need but I assume you can develop a headless call for your application, then write a cmd script that launch every installation headless with a different login informations and you can track on your login server the consequences....